# Converting time.struct_time into a string using formatting

Tags: python, date, time, format

I have in this format:

```
(Pdb) aa = time.strptime("2015-02-28 14:19:05.512", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
(Pdb) aa
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=14, tm_min=19, tm_sec=5, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=59, tm_isdst=-1)
```

How can I convert it into a string `'2015-02-28T14:19:05'`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use [`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) , Example -

```
import time
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S',time.strptime("2015-02-28 14:19:05.512", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
>> '2015-02-28T14:19:05'
```

---

But you should consider using [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module which is more powerful for parsing/working with dates/times. Example -

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-02-28 14:19:05.512", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
>> '2015-02-28T14:19:05'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use datetime instead of time.

```
from datetime import datetime
aa=datetime.strptime("2015-02-28 14:19:05.512", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
str(aa)
```

Should give you what you are looking for.

Comment: `str(datetime.datetime.strptime("2015-02-28 14:19:05.512", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))` gives me - `'2015-02-28 14:19:05.512000'`

Comment: @AnandSKumar, Yes I did not really try the code but I see that you also posted a solution that solve the problem. No need for me to push again.